# Delete sheets with less than 15 rows

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have an Excel workbook of very many sheets with data but I want to keep only those with 15 or more rows. Here is the code I have but once it hits a sheet with less it deletes everything:

```
Sub LastRowWithData_xlUp_1()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If lastRow < 15 Then Ws.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: move `lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` inside loop and change it to `lastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: WOW tanks you help me alot

Answer (score 0):

Copying @simoco's Comment for the sake of an answer:

> move `lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
>    inside loop and change it to
>    `lastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`